# Getting active thread counts and threads in queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

Here is a quick pseudo of my app
ImageDT is a DataTable

```
Parallel.ForEach(ImageDT.AsEnumerable(), row =>
{
    if (a1 != a2)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Foo1, row["foo"])
    }
    else 
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Foo2, row["foo"])
    }
}
```

I need to know how many threads are active and how many are queued for Parallel and the ThreadPool.

Thanks

Comment: GetAvailableThreads  will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads.aspx

Comment: what do a1 and a2 represent?

Comment: Having multithreaded code that creates threads is...generally not a good idea.  YOu'll usually want to either have serialized code spawning new threads, or multithreaded code that does serialized work.

Comment: Servy can you give examples or point me to a site explaining more with examples? This app has to run as fast as the cpu will let it. Large amounts of data being thrown at it. ImageDT that i'm currently working with contains 193,000+ rows and the ThreadPool threads are searching another datatable that has 27,000+ rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of a couple of shared integers, "Queued" and "Active." Increment Queued when you queue a WorkItem. When your callback method starts, have it decrement Queued and increment Active. When the callback exits, decrement Active.

Comment: I used Interlocked for it.

Comment: Good point, as increments/decrements aren't atomic. I'd also recommend that the counters are declared volatile.